# Transition between web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I have 4 different html web pages. Each contains only a background photo. I want to make a site with the following:

- An index page
- Buttons to access the other pages

However, I need the browser view to slide horizontally upon navigation to the next page. How can I do this?

Additionally, all my images are 1280x800, and I am worried about them fitting inside browser windows with low resolutions, since I do not want to have a scroll bar.

Comment: Not sure why your question was down voted, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer with a script!**

I made this a while ago and figure it could help you out greatly and give you an idea.

What I am doing is fading in and out the main divs based on which nav link is clicked. It acts as if it was a multi-page website but in reality it is just fading one in and the other out.

Here is how the html structure should look:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="mainNav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="port">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="wrapper-home" class="body active">
    <p>Here is some content!</p>
</div>
<!-- Etc, etc, etc -->
```

Now the script that makes this happen, with the use of css:

```
$('ul.mainNav li a').on('click', function() {
    $('ul.mainNav li a').parent().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var wrapper = $('#wrapper-' + id);

    $('.body').removeClass('active');
    $(wrapper).addClass('active');
});
```

finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M9aLE/show/)

---

-1. You can set the image as a background-image. Then in your css you can add the follow:

```
background-image: url("yourImageUrl.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

That will allow the image to fit the entire page and keep the images proportions.

-2. The best option, in my eyes, is to make everything on one page. Then you hide and show the divs that contain the info while adding a transition effect.

Comment: For 1). It don't shows me a few lines of pixeles from the bottom. Don't shows entire image when the width is too large

Comment: That is due to the image keeping it's proportion. If you don't want that then your image will be horribly distorted across the millions of different monitor sizes. For the first part, did you want it to? You said a full screen image.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the href target of your links and replace with a javascript function which performs a transition and then page change

Old link:

```
<a href="page.html">link to next page</a>
```

New link:

```
<a href="javascript:transitionTo('page.html');">link to next page</a>
```

Then with some javascript:

```
function transitionToPage(sNewPage){
    // insert your transition out fade effect code here
    window.location = sNewPage;
}
```

If you also want to handle transitioning into a page, then I recommend having a default blank type look for the page, then onload transition from that to the content

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // insert your transition code from blank page or whatever default to desired look
});
```

This will however only be JS compatable, and not work in ~1.5% of browsers. So I recommend actually using a lazy link load technique:

```
<a class="lazy_load_link" href="page.html">link to next page</a>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sTarget = $(".lazy_load_link").attr("href");
    $(".lazy_load_link").attr("javascript:transitionToPage('"+sTarget+"');');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nr 1. Place a background using CSS and set background-size to cover.

Nr 2. Make an onclick on a span. And style it as a button.

```
<span onclick="goToPage('home.html')">Home</span>
```

Javascript:

```
function goToPage(page){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').fadeOut(2000, function(){
   window.location=page;
  });
 });
}
```